# Error: multidex-config.pro, Failed to read file: multidex-config.pro

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error:
>   multidex-config.pro, Failed to read file: multidex-config.pro     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.shaking.ProguardConfigurationParser.parse(ProguardConfigurationParser.java:163)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexListCommand$Builder.makeCommand(GenerateMainDexListCommand.java:113)

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        multiDexKeepProguard(new File("multidex-config.pro"))
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure about the path, it should be in root of project and please specify path correctly in file object